# RoR - image with link, error showing the ID in the url-for but not in the image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, onclick, partial, rjs

I have the following code in a partial:

```
<%= image_tag(url_for(:controller => "campaigns", :action=>'coupon_preview_text',
:id => campaign_id, :width=>width), {
          :title=>@campaign_name,
          :onclick=>"showBigCouponPreview(" + campaign_id.to_s + ")",  
:alt => @campaign_name }) %>
```

It's working 100% ok when I have a regular rails action display it, e.g. I get

```
<img title="Click for Largest image" 
src="/campaigns/coupon_preview_text/1075?width=120" 
onclick="showBigCouponPreview(1075)" 
alt="Click for Largest image">
```

but when I am using the same partial (that has the image_tag) through an ajax call (for the same record) that used rjs to page.replace_html the partial I am getting

```
<img title="Click for Largest image" 
src="/campaigns/coupon_preview_text/1075?width=120" 
onclick="showBigCouponPreview(#&lt;Campaign:0x7fe795a32210&gt;)" 
alt="Click for Largest image">
```

**i.e. the record id - 1075 - shows ok in the src attribute but not in the onlick action ???**
For some reason that I don't know when the ajax call use rjs to replace that partial it seems to behave differently for the same record.

Clearly there is some sort of issue about getting and showing the records ID as opposed to its internal object ID for the on-click part.

Comment: Seems like instead of integer, you have instance of `Campaign` there. Are these views for the same action? Show us your RJS template. Maybe you mistyped there and pass `campaign` to `:locals` instead of `campaign.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you're setting `campaign_id` in your ajax call, you must be setting it to your actual `Campaign` object rather than the object's ID. The reason it works for the `:id` parameter is because Rails knows to use the object's ID, whereas `.to_s` doesn't.

Comment: yes that what it seems - but why does the same attribute - campaign_id - work in the 'src' attribute but not in the 'onlick action' where I get the object id.  It's called the same variable name

Comment: Because when you set it in your non-ajax method, you're probably actually setting it to the id, not the object. Post your ajax method's code/rjs template and I can give you more info.

Comment: I found it (thanks to this hint from Dylan).  Indeed I am using id's in one place that calls this partial and in another I am using Active Record objects, I was able to fix this by adding .map(&:id) to the end of the one that was using Active Record and now both callers are using the same thing (just ID) it works!